# how to stop cron service in macOS catalina 10.15.3

Tags: catalina

the mac book pro create many cron process.I deleted all cron tasks and it still not work and created many cron process.How to stop? if I ignore this problem,it would create thousands of processes and make my PC stuck.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["cron" processes spawning and piling up, but no crontab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373915/cron-processes-spawning-and-piling-up-but-no-crontab) (possible duplicate)

Comment: I don't know if this is a dupe as there's lots of missing info.  However, please indicate if you upgraded to Catalina or did a clean installation.  Also, please post the output of the following commands:  `crontab -l` and `sudo crontab -l -u root`