# What are the numerous 'cron' tasks in Activity Monitor memory section?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, memory, activity-monitor

I just took a look at my activity monitor (to see if I could optimize my RAM), and saw at the bottom of the memory section a huge amount of root tasks simply titled 'cron' (screenshot below).

[image]

They don't seem to use that much of memory, but I was wondering what they are used for, and why their are so many (around 60% of all my tasks in memory).

I run macOs Catalina 10.15.3 on a MacBook Pro 16 from 2019.

Comment: You’ve got a nice loop. Have you disabled cron entirely and then worked through your entries one by one - watching how it spreads?

Comment: Related question here: ["cron" processes spawning and piling up, but no crontab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/373915/18101)

Comment: You (or a program you ran) created these. These are not part of the default system.